# undefined reference to 'sprintf' [Micropython for STM32]

Tags: c, arm, stm32, cross-compiling, micropython

I'm working on a project in which I'm using **Micropython**'s minimal sample code for my **STM32 board**. The Micropython interpreter on my STM32 board runs without issues (I modified the low-level libraries). Now for customising Micropython and building a few modules which shall read some value from the local variables and load it to display. Hence, I'm trying to use the IO functions, i.e. sprintf( ), but unfortunately, my compiler `arm-none-eabi-ld` is throwing an error (given below).

```
arm-none-eabi-ld: build/modmyport.o: in function `board_clockinfo':
../micropython/ports/minimal/modmyport.c:46: undefined reference to `sprintf'.
```

At first, I thought that the flag in makefile `-nostdlib` prevents the compiler from using the regular standard libraries. But even after removing them, I still got the same error.
https://github.com/micropython/micropython/blob/master/ports/minimal/Makefile

```
#makefile in the minimal port, CROSS = 1
CFLAGS_CORTEX_M4 = -mthumb -mtune=cortex-m4 -mcpu=cortex-m4 -msoft-float -fsingle-precision-constant -Wdouble-promotion -Wfloat-conversion
CFLAGS += $(INC) -Wall -Werror  -std=c99 -nostdlib $(CFLAGS_CORTEX_M4) $(COPT)
LDFLAGS += -nostdlib -T stm32f405.ld -Map=$@.map --cref --gc-sections
```

Moreover: I think that it might be some linking or definition-related issues.

```
/*Because in the code given below*/
int a = 5 ;
sprintf(buffer,"this is just for test\n\r"); /*This is working*/  
sprintf(buffer,"this is just for test=%d\n\r",a); /*This is not working*/
```

Does anyone know what I can do to resolve this issue? Any hint or support is highly appreciated.

Comment: what C library are you using/linking?

Comment: I'm using basic standard libraries: stdio.h, stdlib.h, stdint.h and string.h.

Comment: those are not libraries those are header files.  for baremetal you have to provide a C library, newlib is often used but others can be used, and you have to link it in if you want it to.....link in...and before that you have to build it, deal with the bootstrap and linker script and all the things.  C library is painful at best, the printf family sucks in a ton of the C library and you really really really need to think hard about C library and then printfs.

Comment: did it work before and now it doesnt? or you just now added sprintf and now it doesnt link?

Comment: You have -nostdlib in both the CFLAGS and LDFLAGS.  Did you take it out of both?  It shouldn't be in CFLAGS even if you do really want it in LDFLAGS.

Comment: @old_timer when I mention standard libraries, I was saying that the c library is also there (not just the header file). As you can see at the bottom, sprintf with two ARGS is working but not with multiple ARGS. Most probably, the ARM compiler is restricting the lengthy definitions and replacing them with smaller ones (to reduce the memory size, maybe).

Comment: @TomV Yes, I tried all possible combinations, removing both of them and removing the individuals. Still, the error is the same.